# Vue component doesn't show registers from api

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

Please help with this problem
I'm trying to show registers from an api route (/api/orders) 
When I call them from axios, I use get petittion to /api/orders

This is my method:

```
listarOrdenesIngreso (page,buscar,criterio) {
    let me=this;
    var url= '/api/orders?page=' + page + '&buscar='+ buscar +'&criterio='+ criterio;
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            var respuesta= response.data;
            me.arrayOrders = respuesta.orders.data;
            me.pagination = respuesta.pagination;
            // handle success

         })
........
```

Here is the API route routes/api.php file

```php
Route::resource('orders', 'EntryOrderController',['except' => ['create','edit']]);
```

and here the code of controller (EntryOrderController.php file)

```php
public function index(Request $request) 
    { if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
     $entries = EntryOrder::all(); 
    //return response()->json(['data' => $entries], 200); 

    return $this->showAll($entries); 
}
```

[image]

The problem It shows in image 1, where not show any register in my vue component When I call them from the URL in the browser, show me correctly the array with data.
[image]

I hope you can help me Thanks

Comment: what you return from showAll method ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the request result data not founded

```
 `listarOrdenesIngreso (page,buscar,criterio){
                let me=this;
                var url= '/api/orders?page=' + page + '&buscar='+ buscar + '&criterio='+ criterio;
                axios.get(url)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        me.pagination = response.pagination;
                        me.arrayOrders = response.data.data; // do this 
                    //me.arrayOrders = respuesta.orders.data; // errors here

                        // handle success

                    })
```

Comment: Hi @Birante
with 
<code>me.arrayOrders = respuesta.data; </code>
The arrayOrders is filled with the data.
But I still not be able to show in view
Thanks for your comment

Comment: Finally, in my vue Orders Component, I had some fields that are not present in my arrayOrders. I delete these fields and works.
Thanks